# Angular.js fails to load Google maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I am new to Angular. I have been trying to load Google Maps, but it's still failing to work. I found a link on the web and followed all of the steps they used, but it still fails to load. I also tried other samples found on the net, but it still fails. Here is the link to the document I followed:

http://www.saintsatplay.com/blog/2015/03/using-google-maps-in-angular-js#.VmLTBaeIZCU

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        .angular-google-map-container {
            height: 300px; // Or whatever pixel value you require :)
        }
    </style>

    <script src="components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers/Drivermap_controllers.js"></script>        
</head>
<body ng-app='driverapp'>
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Drivermap_controllers.js**

```js
"use strict";
var app = angular.module('driverapp', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
    .config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
        uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
            key: '***********',
            v: '3.17',
            libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
        });
    })
    .controller("DrivermapController", function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
        // Define variables for our Map object
        var areaLat      = 44.2126995,
            areaLng      = -100.2471641,
            areaZoom     = 3;

        uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
            $scope.map     = { center: { latitude: areaLat, longitude: areaLng }, zoom: areaZoom };
            $scope.options = { scrollwheel: false };
        });
    });
```

**main.js**:

```js
var app = angular.module('driverapp', ['ngRoute','ngResource']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/customers', {
            templateUrl: 'views/customers/new.html',
            controller: 'CustomersListController'
        })
        .when('/drivermap', {
            templateUrl: 'views/drivermap/new.html',
            controller: 'DrivermapController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/customers'
        });
});
```

**views/drivermap/new.html**:

```html
 <div ng-controller="DrivermapController">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" options="options" zoom="map.zoom"></ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

error in the console:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=driverapp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DuiGmapgoogle-maps%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.8%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DuiGmapgoogle-maps%250AG%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250Ade%252F%253C%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A186%250Ab%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A251%250Ade%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A1%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A117%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A331%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A488%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A134%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A331%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A488%250Aeb%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A249%250Ayc%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A19%253A463%250Ayc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A274%250AZd%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A19%253A83%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A294%253A192%250An.Callbacks%252Fj%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fjquery%252Fdist%252Fjquery.min.js%253A2%253A26920%250An.Callbacks%252Fk.fireWith%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fjquery%252Fdist%252Fjquery.min.js%253A2%253A27738%250A.ready%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fjquery%252Fdist%252Fjquery.min.js%253A2%253A29530%250AI%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9001%252Fcomponents%252Fjquery%252Fdist%252Fjquery.min.js%253A2%253A29721%250A%0AG%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A391%0An%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A331%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A488%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A134%0An%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A331%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A488%0Aeb%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A249%0Ayc%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463%0Ayc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274%0AZd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A83%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A294%3A192%0An.Callbacks%2Fj%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fjquery%2Fdist%2Fjquery.min.js%3A2%3A26920%0An.Callbacks%2Fk.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fjquery%2Fdist%2Fjquery.min.js%3A2%3A27738%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fjquery%2Fdist%2Fjquery.min.js%3A2%3A29530%0AI%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9001%2Fcomponents%2Fjquery%2Fdist%2Fjquery.min.js%3A2%3A29721%0A

Comment: from the article you posted: "Pay attention to the order in which the above files are loaded: lodash.min.js MUST come before angular.min.js and angular-google-maps.min.js."  Have you tried this?  If so, then the next step would be to use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` so that you can get a readable error output.  Also, I don't actually see `angular-google-maps.min.js` in your scripts.

Comment: Thanks i have modified my code as you suggested an now i have this error     :  Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module driverapp due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.directives.api due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.directives.api.models.parent due to:

Comment: did you add the missing library `angular-google-maps.min.js`?

Comment: yes i did angular-google-maps.min.js

Comment: @akaiz, did you try to add to add a reference to  [angular-simple-logger](https://github.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger)?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect (in your comment you did not provided the complete console error) you are using version [`2.2.X`](http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.2.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js) of [angular-google-maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps), this version has an additional dependency on [angular-simple-logger](https://github.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger). The solution would be to explicitly add reference to [angular-simple-logger](https://github.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger), modify `index.html` file:

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger/master/dist/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iswIatzUhs9qbpiV1IEA?p=preview)